# Mimicking a search bar in command line? Improved autocomplete

Tags: bash, google-chrome, search, command-line, terminal

I use terminal on Mac and Cygwin on Windows. I love that if I can't quite remember something, I can always use 'tab' to suggest available files and folders.

I was wondering if there's anyway to get a terminal to feel more like the google search bar?

For example, in chrome, if I want to go to twitter, I just type 'tw' in the omni bar and google suggests tw**itter.com** (the bolded portion is highlighted). I'm free to ignore the suggestion and type something else, but if I want to take it, I just press enter. As I type more letters, the bar adapts and suggests other possible searches that begin with my typed letters.

Just wondering if anyone has run into anything that makes something like this possible in a command line? As an example, if I start to type

```
cd so
```

It would display so**me_directory**

Where the bolded portion is the 'suggestion'. In this case, assume some_directory is the only directory that starts with 'so'.

Has anyone come across auto complete functionality like this in a command line?

Comment: `bash` completion maybe

Comment: What do you mean by "go to twitter" from the command line? The shell doesn't need to rely on a 3rd party to suggest completions you want: you can define your own functions to automate common commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other forums suggested the autosuggestion feature in [zsh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) and [fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_autosuggestions). This is exactly what I was looking for.